# CalculateRollupField Dynamics WebAPI

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am trying to call the `CalculateRollupField` WebAPI call from [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) for [microsoft-dynamics](/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics).  I can't seem to find many examples of the implementation and my attempt at following the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt718083.aspx) throws the error:

> The request URI is not valid.  The segment 'CalculateRollupField' cannot include key predicates, however it may end with empty parenthesis

### WebAPI Call

```
https://crm.com/api/data/v8.0/CalculateRollupField(ccseq_contracts(FFA8E06D-30AD-E711-80E8-005056B33317), ccseq_totalamount)
```

What do I need to adjust to get this WebAPI call to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct url is below

```
https://crm.com/api/data/v8.0/CalculateRollupField(Target=@tid,FieldName=@field)?@tid={'@odata.id':'ccseq_contracts(3047FD4D-CCC3-E711-80E9-005056B33317)'}&@field='ccseq_totalamount'
```